# How can we go from uniform integrable to uniform L1

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

To be specific, if we have a set of $\{f_n\}$ measurable functions, uniform integrable:

For any $\epsilon>0$, we can find a $\delta$, such that for any set E with $\mu\{E\}<\delta$, $|\int f_nd\mu|<\epsilon$.

I want to know how we can control $\int|f_n|d\mu$ from that.
There is a similar question asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269570/technical-step-in-vitalis-theorem). However that's just for the $f_n$ real case, where we can seperate $f$ to $f^+$ and $f^-$ on two measurable sets. I wonder how can we deal with the complex case?

My idea is as following:

$\int|f|d\mu=\int\sqrt{(Ref)^2+(Imf)^2}d\mu\le \sqrt{\int((Ref)^2+(Imf)^2)d\mu)}\sqrt{\mu(E)}$

While $\mu(E)$ is a finite constant, $\int((Ref)^2+(Imf)^2)d\mu=\int(Ref)^2d\mu+\int(Imf)^2d\mu$.

However from the uniform integrability we can only deduce that $\int(Ref)d\mu$ and $\int(Imf)d\mu$ are controlled, while for a finite measurable set $E$ we cannot get from $L^1$ to $L^2$ ($L^2 \subset L^1$) and this is where I'm stuck at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $f=u+iv$ with $u,v$ real valued. The reduction of complex case to the real is based on 
$$
\left|\int_E u\,d\mu  \right| = \left|\operatorname{Re}\int_E f\,d\mu  \right|\le  \left|\int_E f\,d\mu  \right|
$$
and similarly 
$$
\left|\int_E v\,d\mu  \right| = \left|\operatorname{Im}\int_E f\,d\mu  \right|\le  \left|\int_E f\,d\mu  \right|
$$
So, if $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly integrable, the corresponding families $\{u_n\}$ and $\{v_n\}$ are uniformly integrable. This gives you uniform $L^1$ bounds for $u_n$ and $v_n$. Finally, the triangle inequality yields
$$\int_E |f|\,d\mu = \int_E (|u+iv|)\,d\mu\le \int_E |u|\,d\mu+\int_E |v|\,d\mu$$